# How to add force when exiting a portal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple script that teleports me when I enter a portal. The problem is that when I exit the portal, the force is no longer there. When I jump downwards into a portal and there is another portal sideways, I want it to push my player forward depending on the speed of entry of portal 1.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class portal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject portal2;
    public GameObject player;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (player.transform.position != portal2.transform.position)
        {
            if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                player.transform.position = portal2.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general it sounds like you have a Rigidbody so use `GetComponent<Rigidbody>(). position` instead of `transform.position`

Comment: this worked but i want the force to be more noticable

Answer (score 0):

In general you should strongly avoid mixing `Rigidbody` with transformations via the `Transform` component. This breaks the physics and often leads to unexpected behavior.

Rather use e.g.

```
public class portal : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Giving your fields the correct types
    // reduces property accesses or GetComponent calls
    public Transform portal2;
    // additionally this makes sure that you can now only reference an object
    // which actually has a Rigidbody component
    public Rigidbody player;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (player.position != portal2.position)
        {
            if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                player.position = portal2.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you want a more notable effect you could  either add some force in the same direction the player moves like

```
player.position = portal2.position;
player.AddForce(player.velocity.normalized * force);
```

where `force` is a fixed value you could get via the Inspector.

Or alternatively you could also directly manipulate the velocity by a fixed factor like e.g.

```
player.position = portal2.position;
player.velocity *= 1.1f;
```

Comment: This didn't really work but thanks for the input. it stays the same